# RegEx not matching when using Select String

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I've verified that my regex is correct with this code:

```
#this is the string where I'm trying to extract everything within the []
$text = "MS14-012[2925418],MS14-029[2953522;2961851]"
$text -match "\[(.*?)\]"
$matches[1]
```

Output:

```
True
2925418
```

I'd like to use Select-String to get my result, like this for example:

```
$result = $text| Select-String -Pattern $regex
```

Output:

```
MS14-012[2925418],MS14-029[2953522;2961851]
```

What else I've tried:

```
$result = Select-String -Pattern $regex -InputObject $text
$result = Select-String -Pattern ([regex]::Escape("\[(.*?)\]")) -InputObject $text
```

And some more variations as well as different kinds of " and ' around the regex and so on. I'm really out of ideas...

Can anyone please tell me why the regex is not matching when I'm using Select-String?

Comment: Hint: pipe the output to Get-Member

Comment: Oh, I need to access $results.Matches. Thanks! :)

Comment: Pipe the Matches property to Get-Member and you should be far enough down the rabbit hole :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After piping the output to Get-Member I noticed that Select-String returns a MatchInfo object and that I needed to access the MatchInfo.Matches property to get the result. Thanks to Mathias R. Jessen for giving me the hint! ;)

Comment: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" I'll do it as soon as it's possible :)